# Rotate nginx logs every 30 minutes with logrotate

Tags: logging, nginx

Can I rotate the `nginx` log every 30 minutes?

Like:

- `10:30.log`
- `11:00.log`
- `11:30.log` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if logrotate.d supports 30 minutes intervals or not. However, you could write the logrotate.d config for nginx and then fire logrotate every 30 minutes via cron.